# The possessive pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, possessive-pronouns

One sees something like that and the picture forms in **one's / their / his / her** mind?

Which of the above possessive pronouns are preferable/correct?

Comment: or *You hear something like that and a picture forms in your mind.*

Answer (score 2):

The posessive pronoun you're looking for is referring to the subject, "one" in your case. In this situation the correct usage is "one's":

> One sees something like that and the picture forms in one's mind.

When the subject changes, you will have to change the posessive pronoun:

> Mike sees something like that and the picture forms in his mind.
>
> People see something like that and the picture forms in their mind.